# How to set multiple regions Load-Balancers Alias records to a single name in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a single **A name**: `api.example.com`
I have 2 **Load-Balancers**: 1 in **Virginia**, another in **Frankfort**

So how can I set the 2 **Load-Balancers** to the single **A name** on the top in AWS Route 53 ?

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a setup?

Comment: @Marcin The uses of my WebApp are located principally in US and in EU. But the database is in US. I already have a Load Balancer in US that serves an EC2 and I would like to add another one in EU so that will also serves an EC2 located in EU.

Comment: So based on geographic location?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, so that the requests are redirected to the nearest Load Balancer

Comment: Have you tried to setup a record set with [geolocation routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo)? If yes, what issues do you find with that?